# PostgreSQL помогите составить запрос

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица с названием файлов и датой их создания:

```
SELECT filepath, date FROM files ;

filepath       |            date
---------------+----------------------------
file1          | 2018-05-10 12:40:02.888316
file2          | 2018-05-10 12:40:02.891425
file3          | 2018-05-10 12:43:49.406967
file4          | 2018-05-10 12:43:49.409698
file5          | 2018-04-27 16:45:40.312397
file6          | 2018-05-10 12:43:49.411634
```

Я знаю как сделать SELECT, чтобы посмотреть в какой день сколько файлов   создалось:

```
SELECT count(*), date(date) FROM files group by date(date) order by date;

 count |    date
-------+------------
    15 | 2018-04-27
     5 | 2018-04-28
     7 | 2018-04-29
     1 | 2018-04-30
     14| 2018-05-01
     11| 2018-05-02
```

Подскажите, как выгрузить данные, чтобы отображалось сколько всего cfg-файлов было на определенную дату из столбца `date`?

Необходимы вывод:

```
count  |    date
-------+------------
    15 | 2018-04-27
    20 | 2018-04-28
    27 | 2018-04-29
    28 | 2018-04-30
    42 | 2018-05-01
```

Comment: Что значит `cfg-файл`?

Comment: Не понял про cfg файлы. И чем плох работающий запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нарастающий итог можно получить с помощью [оконной функции](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) с указанием сортировки внутри окна.

```
select sum(count(1)) over(order by date(date)), date(date)
  from files
 group by date(date)
```

Тест на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26c9e/5)